# event to occur on time interval not on click

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Dears,
The below function occures when i click on a button, I need to make it happen every 5 seconds,I'm using the below but it doesn't work :

```
var angle = 0;
function galleryspin(sign) { 
  spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
  if (!sign) { 
    angle = angle + 45; 
  } else {
    angle = angle - 45; 
  }

  spinner.setAttribute("style",'-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); -moz-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg);');
}

setInterval(galleryspin('-'),500);
```

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace *setInterval(galleryspin('-'),500);* with the following

```
setInterval(()=>galleryspin('-'),500);
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval() can't have a function parameter with a parameter.

```
setInterval(galleryspin('-'), 500);
```

A solution for this is to call your function in an anonymous function

```
setInterval(function() {galleryspin('-')}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call the function inside setInterval. However you can use anonymous function or you can pass any number of arguments after delay

```
setInterval(galleryspin, 500,'-');
```

click for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things that could make this program fail:

- You are calling the function once; the setInterval syntax is incorrect. You must not call the function using parentheses, just point to it using the name. Using parentheses calls it once at the beginning, then never again.
- If you remove the parentheses, then you cannot input arguments. To solve this, set the default argument to '-'. You could also use an anonymous function.